# Simulate backdrop wall mount using autopole

Tags: equipment-recommendation, backdrops

I want to buy two autopole to create a background setup.
My issue is that most of the setups I have seen until now, the autopoles are visible.
Is there any clamp or something that would make it possible to attach the background paper and the autopoles to be hidden just behind the paper.

Here is a picture on what I want to have

[image]

This is usually achieved when you have with wall background mounts but I cannot mount anything in the wall so I want to achieve this using autopoles.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but if you are framing an image that is within the backdrop (and you are not showing the edges of the backdrop), why does it matter if the stands are visible *outside* of the backdrop?

Answer (score 1):

The rollers for the seamless must be mounted at the ends.

You would need to make what is essentially a section of wall (say from 3/4" plywood) that could be mounted to the autopoles with any variety of pipe clamps. If you needed it to be more portable you could use small truss clamps.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for pole which is like a hanger. This can help you to hide the pole behind a backdrop. [Here](https://www.essentialphoto.co.uk/products/table-top-background-stand) is one example to show what I mean.

[Here](https://www.rainbow-camera.com/en/products/rsc-collapsible-chroma-key-green-sreen) is another example (with green chroma screen in this case) you can attach with single pole.

P.S. No affiliation with any of the manufacturers or sellers

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no out of the box solution fro what you want.

However, you could check out normal wall mounted background set, get the specification to a metal worker and ask the person how much it would be to weld them to a metal frame in the correct width and attach something that can be temporarily fastened to your two auto poles.

Unless the frame will be collapsible, this solution will be a bit on the bulky side, as it has to be the width of your background rolls.